# Left-looking organization

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]
[Plaintext grid](https://pastebin.com/5LH2qZGH)

**Across**
7. Fly comes flying around place near North Carolina, showing certain smugness (4-11)
9. ISIS fighters maybe capture one town's leader and, among others, foremost loyal people holding on to land rights (15)
10. Pharmacy can offend extremists... and may finally send help to sister's disease (15)
13. For each hotel retreat, resort with baths, maybe (7)
15. Marx's *Capital*, in Oxford University collection, held at first in possession of left-looking organization (7)
16. One-time occupation of someone who cries after Crosby sings, passing by (8,7)
19. Colonel brought in to mark readers and hobbyists (5,10)
21. "Oddly, forest covers minion, decapitated by Native American king", describes historical novel (10,5)

**Down**
1. Messengers are prettier, sweetly modified (15)
2. Carbon-free binding agent supporting a very strong farm house is releasing (15)
3. Work times for Carmen and Don Carlos? (6)
4. Info in Russian? Yes, thank you (4)
5. "I record a remix of rhymes on the outside, taking no heroin" – part of it's true (15)
6. Breed of twisted terrorist ethics (8,7)
8. Replacement of depot chosen (5)
11/12. Morrissey's holding back agreement with superior (3,3)
14. 19 across left out lists, late to make letter (3)
15. Boasting of depression turning around (3)
17. Retired criminal seen by road leading to city in Ireland (6)
18. Countering bias around the start of election, for some time (5)
20. Company imports Ohio salmon (4)

Comment: Should I give my answer? That's too unfair!!! You green-checked an invisible answer!!

Comment: @Scratch---Cat I provided pictures in my answer, but based from what I've seen before, imgur does not work for you, so this seems to be an effect of it. I don't know if that's correct, but whatever the case, I am sad that you can't see it, but jafe accepted my answer because he is able to see the images within it. (Out of curiosity then, did Deusovi's previous answers to jafe's crosswords turn up invisible to you too?)

Comment: @oAlt Yes, invisible too.

Comment: @Scratch--Cat :(( If it helps, then in the (rare) case that I get to be the first to solve the crossword, I'll provide at least the explanations in complete text (assuming jafe has provided already the link to the plaintext grid). (However, if my laziness doesn't take over, I may be able to put up a plaintext answered grid as well.)

Comment: (@Scratch---Cat ** my previous tagging had a typo)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completed! (Thanks to @user70451 and @Stiv...)

> [image]

The clue explanations:

> [image]

Comment: For 3D, think rot13(ovmrg naq ireqv)

Comment: @user70451 thanks! i got that, will edit later

Comment: 14D is rot13(gur Terrx yrggre CUV - fgnzc pbyyrpgbef ner CUVYNGRYVFGF... gnxr bhg YNGR naq YVFGF naq lbh unir CUV!)

Comment: @Stiv interesting :00 that word was never part of my vocabulary, which may have been the root of my struggle :D

Comment: @Stiv Wow, that's a nice clue.